# how to show short version of posts

Tags: php, blogs

I'm writing a blog and I want to show short versions of posts on the main page. I assume native php string functions aren't appropriate here since posts can be large and it would take long to substr all posts in loop.  **So, what is the common strategy here?** I hope the question is clear and specific.

I don't want to shorten posts on client side with JS, that's not an option.

Comment: If your getting the blog data from a database you can use the DB built in of substr, I think its more effective than php built-in (I have no shred of evidence for my thinking). So you would do something like: SELECT ENTRY_NAME, SUBSTR(BLOG_TEXT,1,100) AS BLOG_TEASE FROM MY_BLOGS.

And then you would want to only get the full text once the blog has been selected.

Comment: It's no point of doing this on client side with JavaScript, Ofcourse you can save some time but you loose a lot of bandwitch just to send more data that will be cuted ONLY when user have JS Engine turned on

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms well that's basically the same approach you suggest, isn't it?

Comment: @dKab is this a response to my comment to adrian? If so, its not quite. He stores the shorter description in the database, while I only use one column to hold both and then in my select I specify if I want the whole description or the substring.

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms no, it's reply to the first comment

Comment: @dKab I am confused by what you are asking me then. Anyways, I think the best answer is by Adrian, with his additional comment on his answer. It is both fast and space efficient. If you have any additional questions, please start a chat with me :)

Comment: @IvayloSlavov it wasn't my intent to have full posts and just collapse/show them. The idea is to redirect to the page with full post when user click on "read more" link. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: actually I rushed too early in commenting, @AdrianModliszewski seems to have a point. I'll remove my comments as the discussion seems getting long here, and other posts will now be more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I use is to make another field in db table with posts where I put short version of post, cuted begining or something like that.

It's faster, and better, you don't have to worry about length becouse you control it, there is no problem with evenual html tags used in context, and you can have a bit diffrent text on mainpage

Comment: I feel this additional field would hold so much duplicate data. Why would you not simply use a substr of the text field? (out of my personal curiousity, im not saying your approach is bad, I am new to this and want to understand)

Comment: The duplication is not as big problem as bandwith and time when you have many readers. You can allways add another HardDrive. Another thing is you don't need to put any kind of logic into DataBase (witch is generally bad). Another thing is you can allways display this 'starter' concatenated with the rest of post that is stored in another field, and you don't have duplication

Comment: Ah, I like the part where you say "another thing is you can always display...". That there would keep it fast and reduce duplicate data! +1 for that.

Comment: @AdrianModliszewski 
>you can allways display this 'starter' concatenated 
> with the rest of post that is stored in another field
Yeah, I thought of it myself, but wasn't shure about it. I thought maybe there is some common time-tested approach but apparently everyone invents own bycicles here...

Comment: Well there is as many bycicles as people in the world ;) But there are few quite common concepts

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options. The first one involves you writing excerpts for your blog posts manually. Doing this, you don't have to worry about PHP at all.

If you do want to go ahead and automatically generate excerpts, I would set a upper character limit and then cut at the end of the sentence nearest the chosen limit. This approach may or may not produce good results depending on how your post is written.